# How to create push notifications using ASP.NET Core 2 web server

Tags: asp.net, push-notification

First off, my apologies regarding the nature of this question as I am new to the game and trying to help a friend and realized I can't even help myself with this one.

I am having issues creating push notifications and can only use ASP.NET core 2 web server.  The issue is sending them from the server, I cannot get that done at all.

Is there anybody who can help me, perhaps send the package or code and if so, if the packages could be live as the ones I have found haven't been committed in over 3 years now.

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you in advance guys.

Comment: What code have you already tried?

Comment: we are using azure to host but I don't think it matters.We haven't tried anything as of yet, we did research on PushSharp,onesignal and webpush and none seem to be compatbl with a mobile application

Comment: any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

There are serveral open source NuGet packages available, all with pros and cons. Read the API and sample code before you go with one:

- PushSharp is one of the big players, unfortunately it seems no longer maintained. It does not support Apple’s «new» HTTP API and Google’s HTTP V1 API.
- dotApns: Perfect support but only nor Apple Push.
- Firebase Admin SDK: Far too large, only supports FCM (Android and iOS) but no native/direct iOS support. I didnt like the idea of relaying iOS push messages trough FCM.

So, I went the long way to create my own NuGet package which supports native Android/FCM and Apple/APNS push notifications:

- .NET standard library: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushNotifications.Server
- ASP.NET integration: https://www.nuget.org/packages/PushNotifications.Server.AspNetCore

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a later answer but may help someone in the future, with Google deprecating the legacy api and PushSharp no longer maintained, we were forced to use the google provided library FirebaseAdmin. By the time you are here I assume you have a firebase account and have registered your application there.

Here's what you need to do to send firebase notifications on asp.net

1. Get an authorisation json file from Firebase. Login to your firebase account, select your project, open settings > Service Accounts. From there click Generate new private key, your browser should then download the json file. **Warning: If you have a previously generated key it will stop working immediately.**
2. Copy above file to your project, somewhere the code can access.
3. In visual studio, install FirebaseAdmin via nuget to your project.
4. In your global.asax file, initialise the firebaseadmin client, giving it access to the file from step 1.

```
Dim Options As New AppOptions()
Dim FilePath As String = HostingEnvironment.MapPath($"~/YourFolder/YOURFILENAME.json")
Options.Credential = GoogleCredential.FromFile(FilePath)
FirebaseAdmin.FirebaseApp.Create(Options)
```

5. In whatever class you'll use to send messages, use this.

   ```
        Dim OutgoingMsg as New Message()

        With OutgoingMsg
            .Token = RecipientRegToken 
            .Notification = YourNotification
            .Data = YourData
        End With

        Dim RawResponse = FirebaseMessaging.DefaultInstance.SendAsync(OutgoingMsg)
   ```

The RecipientRegToken is the token the device/app has sent to your server that you will use to send messages to. I'm sure you can figure the rest out from here.

That's it.